# How to change string date "2 February 2019" to date(Y-m-d)

Tags: php

I used a screen scraper to get my date which looks like, 2 February 2019, I wish to change this string date to a date format Y-m-d. Can a string such as "2 February 2019" be converted to a PHP date(Y-m-d)?

I found this question different from others because none used my date format and none of the other questions worked for me.

I have tried strtotime but it gives me a day of 1970-01-01.

```
// Find date
$Date = $url->find("div.row-1", 0)->find("div.date", 0)->find("span", 0);
echo $Date . "<br>";
$Date1 = strtotime($Date);
$Date2 = date("Y-m-d", $Date1);
echo $Date2;

// Find date
$Date = $url->find("div.row-1", 0)->find("div.date", 0)->find("span", 0);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date));
```

The first echo give me that correct date that I am looking for "2 February 2019" I wish to see this date as 2019-02-02.

I got the correct result using:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(trim(strip_tags($Date))));
```

Comment: use format() function

Comment: It can https://3v4l.org/hOUV0

Comment: @user3783243, I have tried that line "as is" and got the correct result. But if I put my $Date variable in I still get 1970-01-01.

Comment: @emma the echo result was 1969-12-31.

Comment: `$Date` may have some HTML tags or some other chars that make `strtotime` to fail. Print `$Date` inside a `<pre>` block to check this out.

Comment: @emma Same result 1969-12-31

Comment: @emma echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(trim(strip_tags($Date)))); WORKED Thank you so much

Comment: In the future use `var_dump` to see what your actual string is.